# Javascript: group data in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out the best way to organize this data in Javascript, so I apologize if this question is broader than usual.

I have data:

```
State, Zip
"CA", "945"
"CA", "934"
"MA", "934"
"MA", "021"
"MA", "021"
 etc.
```

I am trying to create some sort of Javascript Array that I can reference to get all the `Zip` in a certain `State`

This reference might look like:

```
State: "CA", Zip:["945", "934"]
State: "MA", Zip:["934", "021", "021"]
```

Does that make sense? Does something similar work with javascript?

I want to do it this way because on rare occasion a 3-digit `Zip` would exist in two `State`s (as in the example above).

---

I was playing with the below code, but it does not work.

```
var stateArray = [],
var zipMapper = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (_.contains(stateArray,data[i].state) == false) {
        stateArray.push(data[i].state)
        zipMapper.push({state: data[i].state, zips: []})
        zipMapper[data[i].state].zips.push(data[zip])
    } else {
        zipMapper[data[i].state].zips.push(data[zip])
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `data` actually look? The pseudo representation is a bit hard to to tell.

Comment: what is the structure of your data? Is it an array? an object?

Comment: Please provide the data as JSON

Comment: What do you do with the grouped data?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the data is read in as a csv. So I believe it is an array of objects, with each object having one `state` and one `zip`

Comment: @NinaScholz So I have one topojson of states, and one topojson of zips. My goal is to click a state and then show the zips within that state. What this is working on is a crosswalk so I know what zips to show when a state is selected.

Comment: @As3adTintin, then my solution should work for your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change the data structure to version with fast access to the state and their Zips.

```
{
    "CA": [
        "945",
        "934"
    ],
    "MA": [
        "934",
        "021",
        "021"
    ]
}
```

To get zips from `CA`, just take `grouped.CA` or `grouped['CA']`.

The solution, you suggested, need always an interation until the data for a state is found. It makes access slow.

```js
var data = [{ State: "CA", Zip: "945" }, { State: "CA", Zip: "934" }, { State: "MA", Zip: "934" }, { State: "MA", Zip: "021" }, { State: "MA", Zip: "021" }],
    grouped = function (array) {
        var r = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            r[a.State] = r[a.State] || [];
            r[a.State].push(a.Zip);
        });
        return r;
    }(data);


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: ah yes that is exactly how I want the data to look. I still need to run through your code (i'm a js newbie), but thanks for the idea and clarification, nina!

Comment: Ok despite that this is only four lines of code, I'm a little confused on `r[a.State] = r[a.State] || [];`. My understanding that this returns the state value unless it evaluates to false, in which case it returns an empty array `[]`. However, there is a state value in every object so why is this needed / what does this actually do?

Comment: for the record, this worked exactly how I was looking, I just want to learn what is happening. thanks!

Comment: @As3adTintin, but in the first time, there is no key in the object.

Comment: Right... but `r[a.State] = r[a.State] || [];` returns `r[a.State]` if `r[a.State]` can be converted to true, and returns `[]` otherwise. wouldn't the first time, with no key in the object, convert to false and thus return `[]`? I feel like I have this backwards...

Comment: yes that is the way, [logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) works.

Comment: but i thought we want `r[a.State]` to return true the first time (creating the key), and then false every other time...

Comment: if `r[a.State]` is truty, an object/array, the the object is returned, not tru or false. if the value is falsey, then an empty array is returned.

Comment: ohhhhhh it makes sense now. Thanks for walking me through that (and for the initial code)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var data = [{
      state: 'CA',
      zip: '945'
    },
    {
      state: 'CA',
      zip: '934'
    },
    {
      state: 'MA',
      zip: '934'
    },
    {
      state: 'MA',
      zip: '021'
    },
    {
      state: 'MA',
      zip: '021'
    },
  ];

  function exists(stateName, data) {
    var existIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].state === stateName) {
        existIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return existIndex;
  }
  var finalData = [],
    index;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index = exists(data[i].state, finalData);
    if (index === -1) {
      finalData.push({
        state: data[i].state,
        zip: []
      })
      finalData[finalData.length - 1].zip.push(data[i].zip)
    } else {
      finalData[index].zip.push(data[i].zip)
    }
  }

  console.log(finalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created code with sample data. This might be helpful:

```
  var data = [{
    state: "CA",
    zip: "945"
  },
  {
    state: "CA",
    zip: "934"
  },
  {
    state: "MA",
    zip: "934"
  },
  {
    state: "MA",
    zip: "021"
  },
  {
    state: "MA",
    zip: "021"
  }
];
var zip_mapper = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (!zip_mapper[data[i].state]) zip_mapper[data[i].state] = []; //zip codes array
  zip_mapper[data[i].state].push(data[i].zip);
}

// testing
for (var key in zip_mapper) {
  alert(key + "--->" + zip_mapper[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how to do it without a loop, relying on reduce only:

Explanation:
Check if element exists in array, if not, then add it to the new **acc array**, if yes, find the index of that element and add the zip number to the zip array.

**Solution**

```js
var data = [{
    state: 'CA',
    zip: '945'
  },
  {
    state: 'CA',
    zip: '934'
  },
  {
    state: 'MA',
    zip: '020'
  },
  {
    state: 'MA',
    zip: '021'
  },
  {
    state: 'MA',
    zip: '022'
  },
];

const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => y.state === x.state);
  if (index < 0) {
    acc.push({
      state: x.state,
      zip: [x.zip]
    });
    return acc;
  }
  acc[index] = {
    ...acc[index],
    state: x.state,
    zip: [...acc[index].zip, x.zip]
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(groupedData)
```